# Smilies in a program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have just made a winform chat client in C#.

I was wondering if there is any way that i could insert smilies in the program.

Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to be more specific, Insert where? into a richtext box?

Comment: Easier with a richtextbox http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R

Comment: You could always just go like `:-)` and be oldschool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an ImageList and put your Smilies Pictures in it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx

Then you can use a KeyDown Event on your Textbox to insert certain Smiley Images whenever a combination like ":-)" etc. is typed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx

Hope I could help you